# Content security policy report-uri using asp page

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-security-policy

I have added below csp settings in my config file:

```
 <add name="Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only" value=  "
    default-src 'none' ;
    script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
    style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ; 
    img-src 'self' csi.gstatic.com dl.edge-cdn.net data: ;
    frame-src 'self';
    font-src 'self' ; 
    object-src 'self' ;
    connect-src 'self' ;
    media-src 'self';
    report-uri /csp_report.aspx?cspReport=true"  />
```

All the settings are working fine. Also I am getting violations in browser console. I want to get all these violations to be reported in csp_report.aspx. But "Request.form" is empty in Page_load event. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The content send to `report-ui` is JSON, not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You can grab it directly from `HttpContext.Request.InputStream` and deserialize it (probably the easiest way will be with JSON.NET as it will be easiest to control property names etc.).

```
string requestJson = String.Empty;

context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
using (StreamReader requestStreamReader = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
{
    requestJson = requestStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
}

// TODO: Deserialize from JSON string or log the JSON
```

Also I would suggest usage of handler (for example `.ashx` file) over page (`.aspx`) as it will be more natural for this use case (returning response with no content and 202 status code would be most suitable here).